# Moose, avoiding explicit boilerplate

Tags: perl, moose

[Best practices](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/BestPractices.pod) recommends `namespace::autoclean` and `make_immutable`

```
package Person;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

# extends, roles, attributes, etc.

# methods

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

[`MooseX::Declare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Declare) automatically handles this but it is deprecated, so
what should be recommended alternative(s) to it?

Comment: Well, there is https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops, but I think you only want the part where it takes the boilerplate, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MooseX::Declare documentation says](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Declare#WARNING):

> If you want to use declarative syntax in new code, please for the love
>   of kittens get yourself a recent perl and look at [Moops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops) instead.

Comment: I don't think OP cares for the actual declarative syntax, but instead only for having less boilerplate.